# How to do two things on delete?

Tags: postgresql

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_a
ADD CONSTRAINT fkey
        FOREIGN KEY (f_id) REFERENCES table_b(id)
            ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

This is a normal constraint, when a tuple is deleted from `table_b`, a corresponding tuple's column `f_id` in `table_a` will be set to `null`.

Here besides set `f_id` to null, I want to set `f_id`'s old value to column `f_old_id`. Is it possible?

Comment: It surely is but you need an `after delete`  trigger on `table_b` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trigger-based solution.

```sql
create or replace function fkey_tf() returns trigger language plpgsql as
$$
begin
 update table_a 
    set f_old_id = f_id, f_id = null
  where f_id = OLD.id;
  return null;
end;
$$;

create trigger fkey_t 
after delete on table_b
for each row execute procedure fkey_tf();
```

Please note that an index on table_a.f_id is needed in order to not sacrifice performance. This is a good practice for foreign keys anyway.